# System DSN not working when running Rails as Windows Service

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

When I run the mongrel server in a command window everything works 
fine, database connections are made and the app is running properly. 
If I set the Windows Service to run my app by logged in with my user 
credentials it works fine as well. However, when I set the Service to 
run as Local System I cannot get the application to start and the log 
file shows the following error;

> Status: 500 Internal Server Error   IM014 (0) [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The  specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

I am running on Windows 7 64bit, and I have tried using odbcad32.exe 
to create the System DSN and the User DSN. 
Can anyone lend a hand, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why I started to look at the problem from a different angle, but found the solution.. Actually the ODBC Data Source Administrator application I was thinking I had to use (from %windir%\system32\odbcad32.exe) was incorrect. When running the application as a Windows Service I needed to have a System DSN setup for the 64bit version of ODBC Data Source Administrator (%windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe). I setup a System DSN using the correct ODBC Data Source Administrator program and my app is working fine.